# is android 64 bit app version necessary if the app is never published through play store

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Can anyone please advice on whether the 64-bit version of app is mandatory if the app is not published through play store?
Usually, our application is deployed through an MDM solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know at the moment this is only mandatory if you deploy apps through the Play Store. A 32-bit app will run on 64-bit processors but it will perform worse than a 64-bit version of the app.
So at the moment there should be no issues besides performance. In future versions of Android though (if only 64-bit hardware will be supported), they may or may not impose a restriction on 64-bit apps running on Android.